# Async Task implementation of httpconnection Post method

Tags: android

Below is the code used.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ContactUs extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button ok;
    EditText name;
    EditText email;
    EditText message;
    String resultname, resultemail, resultmessage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_us);

        //For the submit button
        ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
        ok.setOnClickListener(this);

        //For the value of forms in database
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_name);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_mail);
        message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_message);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId()==R.id.btn_submit){
            class asynctask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{
                private void postdata (){
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    ////zong ip address 192.168.8.103
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.10.33:80/insert 1.php");
                    try {
                        ArrayList <NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                        resultname = name.getText().toString();
                        resultemail = email.getText().toString();
                        resultmessage = message.getText().toString();

                        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name",resultname));
                        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email",resultemail));
                        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Message",resultmessage));

                        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
                        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);



                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("Error",e.toString());
                    }

                }

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    postdata();
                    return null;
                }
            }
            new asynctask().execute((Void) null);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thanks for your Registeration", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();





        }
    }
}
```

Following is the error I am getting

```
06-15 17:21:14.880 14599-14901/com.example.harismahmood.fhfountainhouse W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.HttpHost.<init>(HttpHost.java:83)
06-15 17:21:14.880 14599-14901/com.example.harismahmood.fhfountainhouse W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.determineTarget(AbstractHttpClient.java:521)
06-15 17:21:14.880 14599-14901/com.example.harismahmood.fhfountainhouse W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:511)
06-15 17:21:14.880 14599-14901/com.example.harismahmood.fhfountainhouse W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:489)
06-15 17:21:14.880 14599-14901/com.example.harismahmood.fhfountainhouse W/System.err:     at com.example.harismahmood.fhfountainhouse.ContactUs$1asynctask.postdata(ContactUs.java:67)
06-15 17:21:14.880 14599-14901/com.example.harismahmood.fhfountainhouse W/System.err:     at com.example.harismahmood.fhfountainhouse.ContactUs$1asynctask.doInBackground(ContactUs.java:77)
06-15 17:21:14.881 14599-14901/com.example.harismahmood.fhfountainhouse W/System.err:     at com.example.harismahmood.fhfountainhouse.ContactUs$1asynctask.doInBackground(ContactUs.java:49)
06-15 17:21:14.881 14599-14901/com.example.harismahmood.fhfountainhouse W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-15 17:21:14.881 14599-14901/com.example.harismahmood.fhfountainhouse W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-15 17:21:14.881 14599-14901/com.example.harismahmood.fhfountainhouse W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-15 17:21:14.881 14599-14901/com.example.harismahmood.fhfountainhouse W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-15 17:21:14.881 14599-14901/com.example.harismahmood.fhfountainhouse W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-15 17:21:14.881 14599-14901/com.example.harismahmood.fhfountainhouse W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
06-15 17:21:14.896 14599-14901/com.example.harismahmood.fhfountainhouse E/Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null
```

Comment: why you are creating another method inside asynctask, simply put your code in relative methods. like for network call put that part inside doInBackground and after you receive the response update your UI from onPostExecute method.

Comment: The space in `insert 1.php` might be an issue. Try removing it and renaming the file or encode it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [URLEncoder.encode](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html) as you have spaces between "insert 1.php". It will not allow spaces so you have to encode it

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URLEncoder.encode("http://192.168.10.33:80/insert 1.php"));
```